# How to retrieve id from sqlite database from selected spinner item in ANdroid?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to retrieve selected spinner item id from Sqlite database in Android.When i want to select any spinner item at that time i want to get that get id that spinner item which is i have to select.Thanks in Advanced.
Here is my code

```
spinnerProjectNames = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectProject);
        loadProjectsNameSpinnerData();
        spinnerProjectNames.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                selectedProjectName = spinnerProjectNames.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                System.out.println("selectedProjectName " + selectedProjectName);

                Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT project_id  FROM  project WHERE project_name= '"+selectedProjectName+"'" , null);
                        if (mCursor != null ) {

                            {
                                mCursor.moveToFirst();
                                int projectId=mCursor.getInt(0);
                                String strProjectId = String.valueOf(projectId);



                             System.out.println("strProjectId = " + strProjectId);

                            }

                          }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: Where are you getting your projects from? Can't you just get the `project_id` from the beginning and store it?

Comment: I have add project details in project table and all project_name retrieve from project table in spinner and then when i select any spinner item at that time i want selected spinner item id means project_id.

Comment: I understand that. A good approach is something like this. 1. In the `onCreate` method of your activity retrieve and store the details you will need about a project (project_id, project_name, ...) in a [List](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html). 2. Populate the spinner using the `List`. 3. When the user selects an item, you can retrieve the selected project from the list and use its id, name, ...

Comment: I want to select the project name from spinner drop down list when i select an item ,,i can retrieve the selected id of project name from the spinner drop down list and that id i want to store another SQLite table.

Comment: Please some one help me out